# Sometimes getting crash when getting computed variable

Tags: ios, swift, gmsmapview, computed-properties

I'm getting a crash in the following code:

```
var gmsBounds: GMSMutablePath {
    get {
        let path = GMSMutablePath(with: self.boundaries)
        return path!
    }
}
```

Currently it crashes when initializing the GMSMutablePath according to Crashlytics. However this code isn't ever called before the class is initialized, and self.boundaries is stored during initialization, so I'm not sure how self.boundaries could be nil. I'm also personally unable to recreate the crash, so it is not a bug that affects every user. Any help is appreciated, computed variables are a new concept for me.

Comment: What is the error message/crash log?

Comment: make it lazy var

Comment: @canister_exister this looks like what I needed, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

When I make code reviews always i avoid forced unwrapping, at first sight you can believe that it never will turn to nil but I prefer avoid that

```
return path!
```

Try to unwrapping (safely) it first or change the variable definition for optional:

```
var gmsBounds: GMSMutablePath? {
    get {
        let path = GMSMutablePath(with: self.boundaries)
        return path!
    }
}
```